# Why is this SQL statement hanging when group by, sum, or where clause is included?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL statement:

```
select
   t3.item1,
   t3.item2,
   sum(t1.moneys)
from
   table t1
inner join table t2 on t1.key = t2.key
inner join table t3 on t1.key2 = t3.key2
where
   t2.type = 'thistype'
   and t3.type2 = 'thistype'
group by
   t3.item1, t3.item2
```

If I remove the `group by`, `sum`, or `where` clause it runs fine - but if I add back any of those it hangs forever... any ideas... this is on SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2

Thanks

Further Testing

so I created a view:

```
select
       t3.item1,
       t3.item2,
       t1.moneys,
       t2.type,
       t3.type2
    from
       table t1
    inner join table t2 on t1.key = t2.key
    inner join table t3 on t1.key2 = t3.key2
```

and I can select top 1000 from the view fine and see the type I want to specifically look at in the data, but when I add the 'where type2 = 'thistype'' it hangs again...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: How many records are in these three tables respectively?  Are they indexed?  Are statistics up to date?

Comment: I want to create a view that would have the aggregate value for the t3 item, t1 contains the values that need to be aggregated

Comment: @maple_shaft millions of records, yes, statistics?

Comment: @marc_s I need table 2 in the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your joining three tables together with millions of records, this is normal for it take a bit to run.

To answer your question about statistics, they are what the indices utilize to retrieve records faster from your tables.  Without accurate or up to date statistics, indices can actually slow your queries down.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/rob/archive/2008/05/16/sql-server-statistics.aspx

Comment: Alright I am going to give it like 20 minutes... currently on minute 1

Comment: okay so I made the where clause more specific and it actually returned data so I guess its just the vastness of the data

Comment: Outside of executing a report, there should be very few circumstances where you would need to fetch that many records.  In case you do however, just remember to double check the table statistics.

Answer (score 1):

I think we'd need to see some table structure and know some more things about your DB before we can give a solid answer.  First thing, though, is to run a trace on it and see what that tells you.

At first blush, I have found that issues with aggregate functions (sum, group by, etc) tend to stem from a) overly large data sets (that is: you're just trying to pull back too much data) or b) from overly-complicated structure or relationships on the joined tables.

However, those are just my general rules-of-thumb, and may not apply in a specific situation: run a trace and any other form of profiling you can and see what that tells you.

Comment: @tylercomp - I've always done it by asking by Sql Admin (very nicely) to trace SPID XXXX (whatever my SPID was).

Answer (score 0):

Has you looked at the execution plan you're getting? That will tell you where the problem is. Do you have covering indices on the columns on which you're joining and grouping?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the execution plan is corrupted?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175244(v=sql.80).aspx

Try recompiling the plan using `sp_recompile`